# Publish-AXReport Gives Error "Name cannot begin with the ' ' character"

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, dynamics-ax-2012

Running the below PowerShell script (i.e. to deploy all SSRS reports for AX) gives an error:

```
$axdllname = "Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Management.dll"
$gacfolder = join-path $env:windir "assembly\GAC_MSIL"
$axdll = Get-ChildItem $gacfolder -Recurse -Name $axdllname
$axdll = join-path $gacfolder $axdll
import-module $axdll
Publish-AXReport -ReportName "*" -RestartReportServer
```

The error message is:

```
Publish-AXReport : Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 46, position 8.
At line:1 char:17
+ Publish-AXReport <<<<  -ReportName "*" -RestartReportServer
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Publish-AXReport], XmlException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 46, position 8.,M
icrosoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Management.Reports.PublishReportCommand
```

Sadly I can't find a copy of the source for `Publish-AXReport`, so can't dig deeper into where this exception's coming from.

**Question**

Does anyone know of a likely cause for this issue, or what steps I could take to uncover the cause?

**Update**

Instead of running for all reports using `*` I tried getting a list of all reports (works fine on its own / shows no reports with names beginning with a space) then piping this to the publish-axreport cmdlet; which now means I can see which report(s) produce that error.

`Get-AxReport -ReportName * | Publish-AXReport`

It's now clear that there are several reports (though only a small subset of those available) which throw this error when published.  One of these is `AssetAcquisitionDocumentPL`.

The errors seem to occur only for reports with associated assemblies / always erring for those with; never for those without.

Same issue occurs if running `Get-AXReportServerConfiguration | %{Publish-AXAssembly -id $_.ConfigurationId -vsprojectname 'assetAcquisitionDocumentPL.BusinessLogic'}`

Running the above with the `-verbose` switch shows the error occurs at some point after the assumblies are copied form the temp directory to the SSRS bin directory.

Comment: Looks similar; though probably unrelated: http://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?&t=3661

Comment: Logged here: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/190841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved in this thread: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/190841

**Root Cause**

File `D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.AX2012_ENVIRON1\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rssrvpolicy.config` contained a space between an open bracket and one of the element names; i.e. `< CodeGroup ...>` instead of `<CodeGroup ...>`.

Correcting this typo resolved the issue.

(I don't know how the space got into the file in the first place / doubt I'll find out unless we see this issue again).

**Steps to Discover Cause**

Should anyone have a similar issue with a different cause, here's a verbose version of how we uncovered the issue:

- Download & extract process monitor: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx
- Close all unrequired processes / services (to reduce noise)
- Open `Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Management Shell` as administrator
- Type the command which generates the error (`Publish-AXAssembly -id 'SSRSNLBAOS2' -vsprojectname 'assetAcquisitionDocumentPL.BusinessLogic' -verbose`); select a command which does the least possible work before giving the error (to reduce noise).
- Open Process Monitor
- Run the command
- The moment the error shows, hit Save in process monitor to save the session to a PML file.
- Close process monitor and powershell
- Open the PML file and filter on process name `powershell.exe`
- Look for interesting events.  For me I suspected an XML file, so looked at the file access events near the end of the file.
- Since I'd seen similar issues with XML files before, focussed on the XML (format) files / tried to parse them to see which erred (`[xml][string](get-content 'd:\some\path\to\a\file.config')`).
- When a file didn't parse / gave an error about an invalid space character, that was the culprit file.
- I then opened the file in a text editor and thanks to syntax highlighting spotted the error immediately.
- Correcting the file, saving, then confirming that was the only error in the file by parsing again left the file in a good state.
- I then reran the `Publish-AXAssembly ...` command (without process monitor running) to see if the issue was resolved - it was.

Thanks to @BrandonWiese of the Dynamics Community for his assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have whitespaces (Hexidecimal 0x20) in the report name  which is causing the error.  Please check your script and/or report names to remove the whitespaces.

Line 46, position 8

Comment: Thanks; though that line comes from the `AxDeployReports.ps1` script provided by Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=26571

Comment: See edited answer.